# Understanding Vim commands on paper as keyboard actions

Tags: vim

I am having problems understanding how Vim commands are supposed to be executed as keyboard actions. This is a topic I don't see being discussed often. Some examples are:

```
<s-tab>
```

I believe this is <kbd>s</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> but I don't get the expected results.

```
<c-k>
```

I believe this is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>.

```
<C-k>
```

I sometimes see uppercase `c` but what is the difference?

And, inside of a Vim .vimrc file:

```
noremap <D-M-Left> :tabprevious<cr>
noremap <D-M-Right> :tabnext<cr>
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
map <D-1> 1gt
```

My questions are:

1. What does the case of a letter have to do with the command?
2. Do the `"<"` `">"` braces represent any action?
3. Does the `"-"` dash represent any action?

Comment: Note that `<D-M-Left>` doesn't actually work. MacVim doesn't complain, which is very unfortunate, but it doesn't register the second modifier. `<D-M-Left>` is thus the same as `<D-Left>` which reduces even more the already limited usefulness of that kind of mappings. Worth, `<D->` only works in the MacVim GUI! Better find other methods, like `:h mapleader`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Nothing.  `<c-k>` and `<C-k>` mean the same thing.  By the way, `<s` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. The `<..>` in this context is for <kbd>Control</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combinations. It can have a different meaning in other contexts such as search/replace.
3. The dash is just part of the syntax representing these combinations.

There are other special keys as well such as `<CR>` for <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>, `<Tab>` for <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc.  They are usually intuitive and Vim is pretty flexible in what it will accept for these, especially in terms of case.

Answer (score 12):

I think `:help key-notation` will answer all of your questions about this topic.

Comment: Ah! key notation was the topic i was looking for. Sometimes you dont even know what you should be searching for.

Comment: Yes it happens with Vim but generally the answer is somewhere in the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specifically ask but `<S-Tab>` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and `<c-K>` and `<C-K>` are equivalent and both mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.